# Angular 2 with cordova plugins

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using Angular 2 to build a hybrid app with cordova. I do not use Ionic, so please do not refer to it at all. I use the same Angular code both on the browser and on the mobiles.
I put a folder inside the Angular app which contains the cordova project, and I use a hook script when i call `cordova run android` to build the Angular app and output it into the www folder.
All of this works perfectly, the app builds successfully and everything works fine, but when I try using plugins, here comes the problem.

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Servizio Feste</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type=”text/javascript” src=”cordova.js”></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ngx-app></ngx-app>
  <style>
    .spinner { /* styles */ }
    .global-spinner { /* styles */ }
  </style>
  <div id="nb-global-spinner" class="global-spinner">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I installed the phonegap barcodescanner plugin and I tried to use it in a component as follows:

```
import { AppToasterService } from './../../../../services/toaster.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'qrcode',
  templateUrl: './qrcode.component.html'
})
export class QRCodeComponent {

  constructor(
    private toasterService: AppToasterService
  ) { }

  scanQRCode() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(result => {
      this.toasterService.success(result);
    }, error => this.toasterService.error('Error'));
  }

}
```

When I try to call the scanQRCode() method the following error pops up:

```
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

I searched a lot on already existing issues in stackoverflow but everyone mentions

```
 declare var cordova: any;
```

or loading the cordova.js script in index.html but I already did those things.
Some others said to import cordova.js in the "scripts" section of .angular-cli.json, but also this I tried and it gave me a compilation error saying that cordova.js was not found.
I have also tried to wait for the "deviceready" event in main.ts to bootstrap the app but that event never fires!
Could someone help me please ? I thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to create the interface **.ts file** file for the calling the barcodeScanner.scan.you are getting compile time error or run time?

Comment: I don't get any compilation error. The error occurs when I try to use the scanQRCode() function at runtime.

Comment: I didn't try to use ionic because I don't have time to find out how to write the hook function to use the already written code, because Ionic compiles the typescript itself

Answer (score 0):

It was the stupidest thing: I copied the html script tag from a website and the quotes were encoded in a different way. It was src="cordova.js", and not src=”cordova.js”.